# How to add css in css using js

Tags: html

I am working on a site in which I have bunch of html and css code;
now in css I have written for idle loading and have written some more css code which performs a animation or new css properties with help of transition!

but the twist is
I want to add the new css animation code when a button is pressed (using js).

*For e.g*

```
       <div class="cover-details-signin cover-d" id="cover-signin">
          <h1 class="cover-heading">Welcome Back!</h1>
          <p class="cover-description">
            To keep connected with us please login with your personal info
          </p>
          <a href="#" id="cover-signin-btn auth-btn" class="cover-button"
            >SIGN IN</a
          >
        </div>
        <!-- cover -->
        <!-- cover -->
        <div class="cover"></div>
```

*css*

```
.cover {
  width: 26.2%;
  height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.281);
  */
  background: rgb(3, 185, 104);
  background: linear-gradient(
    47deg,
    rgba(3, 185, 104, 1) 0%,
    rgba(2, 163, 195, 1) 100%
  );
  transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -ms-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -o-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.cover-details-signin {
  z-index: 5;
  min-width: 35% !important;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  color: #ffffff;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  transform: translateX(0%);
  transform-origin: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
  -o-transform: translateX(0%);
  border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -ms-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -o-border-radius: 0.8em 0em 0em 0.8em;
  -webkit-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 1.5s ease-in-out;
}

.cover-details-signin .cover-heading {
  margin-top: 50%;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif !important;
}

.cover-details-signin .cover-description {
  width: 45%;
  margin-top: 1.84812535698526854688856em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.cover-details-signin .cover-button {
  width: 30%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  margin-top: 3em;
  padding: 1.1em 0.5em 1.1em 0.5em;
  /* height: 3em; */
  -webkit-border-radius: 3em;
  -moz-border-radius: 3em;
  -ms-border-radius: 3em;
  -o-border-radius: 3em;
}
```

*CSS code in the same file which I want to start/toggle on button click  button with class .cover-signin-btn*

```
.cover {
  border-radius: 0em 0.8em 0.8em 0em;
  transform: translateX(186.3%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(186.3%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(186.3%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(186.3%);
  -o-transform: translateX(186.3%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 0em 0.8em 0.8em 0em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0em 0.8em 0.8em 0em;
  -ms-border-radius: 0em 0.8em 0.8em 0em;
  -o-border-radius: 0em 0.8em 0.8em 0em;
}

.cover-details-signin{
  /* invisible color */
  color: #e9e9e9 !important;

  /* value for invisible */
  transform: translateX(-200%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-200%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-200%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-200%);
}

.cover-details-signin .cover-button {
  /* invisible border */
  border: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
}
```

PLease help me, how to do it!!!

Comment: you will have to do it with jquery not js .

Comment: actually I also tried addClass toggleClass, .css() and much jQuery, but still it didn't worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to animate onclick of class `cover-button` you must do it by

```
$('.cover-button').onclick(function(){
    $(....).animate({height : "100px"})
})
```